# error while opening a document on SharePoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I am getting the below error while opening a document on SharePoint 2010.

[image: Error Screenshot]

How to resolve the error?

Comment: Do you have a question? Or did you just want to share an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Which office version do you use? Office 2016?

If you use the office 2016, by default in Office 2016 Modern authentication is on. You could turn it off(enableADAL=0).

Go to run->type regedit->then edit register key under the location below:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL  --> D-WORD=0

If not, you could troubleshoot the issue according to the article below.

Excel Document opens as Read-Only and unable to check in the documents.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24150.excel-document-opens-as-read-only-and-unable-to-check-in-the-documents.aspx